# Implement Interface and accessing methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, interface

```
public partial class shoppingCart : ISecurisable
{
    public void Deactivate() 
    {
        shoppingCartid = null;
        IsActive = false;
        foreach (var shoppingCartDetails in Childs)
        {
            shoppingCartDetails.ParentId = ParentId;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I access the `Deactivate()` method after I've implemented ISecurisable on the class.

Comment: `instanceOf_shoppingCart.Deactivate()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can use this form

```
ISecurisable shoppingCart = new shoppingCart();
shoppingCart.Deactivate();

public interface ISecurisable
{
    void Deactivate();
}

public partial class shoppingCart : ISecurisable
{
     public void Deactivate()
     {
         shoppingCartid = null;
         IsActive = false;
         foreach (var shoppingCartDetails in Childs)
         {
            shoppingCartDetails.ParentId = ParentId;
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First create an instance of your `ShoppingCart`-class

```
ShoppingCart cart = new ShoppingCart();
```

Now call the method

```
cart.Deactivate();
```